# In flex, set a property as relative to another, but then lose the connection

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

In Flex 3.0, I made a state which has draggable windows (CollapsableTitleWindow code written by someone else, but that's irrelevant).

Then, I created a new viewstate, which repositions the windows around a bit.

```
<mx:State name="newstate" basedOn="firststate">
    <mx:SetProperty target="{window1}" name="width" value="50%"/>
    <mx:SetProperty target="{window2}" name="x" value="{window1.width + 5}"/>
```

I want to position one window next to the other on load, but I don't want the second window to move when the user drags the first one around.

How can I bind the x to the value of (window1.width + 5) at load, but then lose the continuous evaluation of the thing?

Comment: Have you tried setting the windows `x` value on `creationComplete`?

Comment: No, but creationComplete is apparently only thrown on actual mx-objects. I can't catch it when I change the properties of window2 when the user goes into the newstate-state. Or am I mistaken in this? Autocomplete doesn't suggest it anyway..

Comment: I understand now. You just want to set `x` when the state first changes, not when the component first loads. You could set the `x` property in an event listener for one of the state changing events: **enterState**, **exitState**, **currentStateChange** or **currentStateChanging**. Here's Adobe's documentation: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=using_states_3.html. Let me know if this works and I'll write it up as an official answer.

Comment: This appears to be a strategy. I could only capture enterState on the <mx:State basedOn> declaration. However, when I do "window2.x = window1.width + 5", the value window1.width of the parent state is taken, not the one from the line I have later (and which isn't in my snippet): <mx:SetProperty target="{window1}" name="width" value="50%"/>. You might say: why don't you put the window1.width in the enterState code? Because I cannot set the .width property to a percentage :D

Comment: You **can** set the width to a percentage. Just use the `percentWidth` property in Actionscript. If you can't access the property directly, try using `window1.setStyle("percentWidth", 100);`. I'll write it up as an official answer to help show the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the x property in an event listener for one of the state changing events: **enterState**, **exitState**, **currentStateChange** or **currentStateChanging**.

Here's [Adobe's documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=using_states_3.html).

You could try an event handler for the enterState event :

```
protected function window1_enterStateHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
  window1.percentWidth = 100;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
From Tominator's comments below:

```
Alert.show('before: ' + window1.width.toString() + ' pixels, ' + window1.percentWidth.toString() + '%');  
window1.percentWidth = 50;  
Alert.show('after: ' + window1.width.toString() + ' pixels, ' + window1.percentWidth.toString() + '%');
```

The result is that I get the output:

> before: 458.022705 pixels, NaN%
>   after: 458.022705 pixels, 50%

You may want to try calling `window1.validateDisplayList()` or `validateNow()` after setting the `percentWidth` property.

Comment: It's very unfortunate that percentWidth is an annoying thing. What I did was this (and my formatting will be lost forever I guess): Alert.show('before: ' + window1.width.toString() + ' pixels, ' + window1.percentWidth.toString() + '%'); window1.percentWidth = 50; Alert.show('after: ' + window1.width.toString() + ' pixels, ' + window1.percentWidth.toString() + '%'); The result is that I get the output: before: 458.022705 pixels, NaN%
after: 458.022705 pixels, 50%

Comment: @Tominator I added your code sample to my answer. Have you tried calling `validateNow` or `validateDisplayList` after updating the `percentWidth` property?

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! I had to call validateNow() because window1.validateDisplayList() didn't do anything.. Now I'll just use the enterState for all positioning declarations when they are relative to other items..